# cordova content security policy giving login issue

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ssl

When i am adding this line on my index.html page [which is a login form]

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://codepush.azurewebsites.net/ data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`

It just doesnt go to next form and hangs after pressing the login button.

`index.html:60 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' https://codepush.azurewebsites.net/ data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

See reference image below -
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwr11xb03gpqn8t/Screenshot%202017-04-24%2018.53.24.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Try for all. Use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *  ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ">`